# Spring ws fault issue in wsdl generation

Tags: java, spring, wsdl, jax-ws

My service method inside Endpoint class looks like:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace=AppExternalServicesConstant.NAMESPACE,localPart="AppPurchaseAddonRequest") @ResponsePayload public AppPurchaseAddonResponse purchaseAddon(@RequestPayload AppPurchaseAddonRequest request) throws ServiceExceptionFault {-- Business logic}
```

**XSD looks like following:**

```
        <xs:element name="AppPurchaseAddonRequest" >
            <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:all>
                                <xs:element name="requestId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                <xs:element name="countryCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                <xs:element name="addonName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                <xs:element name="number" type="tns:numberType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                <xs:element name="transactionId" type="tns:transactionIdType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            </xs:all>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="AppPurchaseAddonResponse" >
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="tns:Response">
                        <xs:sequence/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:complexType name="Request">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="requestId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>


        <xs:complexType name="Response">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="responseId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="responseStatus" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="responseDescription" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>


        <xs:element name="ServiceExceptionFault">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="faultInfo" type="tns:AppPurchaseAddonFaultInfo"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element> 




        <xs:simpleType name="numberType">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+"></xs:pattern>
            </xs:restriction>
           </xs:simpleType>

           <xs:simpleType name="transactionIdType">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="20"></xs:maxLength>
                </xs:restriction>
           </xs:simpleType>

           <xs:complexType name="AppPurchaseAddonFaultInfo">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="exceptionStack" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="errorCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="errorDescription" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>



    </xs:schema>
```

**spring-ws-servlet mapping file:**

```
<wss:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ytlc.app"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="file:${environment.properties.file.path}" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" ignore-unresolvable="false"/>


<!-- General properties configuration -->


<!-- Spring Security and Validation configuration -->

 <wss:interceptors>
      <bean class="com.ytlc.ota.ws.services.spring.interceptors.AppPayloadValidationInterceptor">
        <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/xsd/appservicesv1.xsd"/>
        <property name="validateRequest" value="true"/>
        <property name="validateResponse" value="false"/>
      </bean>


</wss:interceptors>

<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver" />  





<!-- Web Services Orchestrated -->

<wss:dynamic-wsdl id="AppServicesV1" portTypeName="AppServicesV1Port" locationUri="/v1/appws" targetNamespace="http://www.yes.my/appservices">
    <wss:xsd location="/WEB-INF/xsd/appservicesv1.xsd"/>
</wss:dynamic-wsdl>
```

In the generated wsdl, ServiceExceptionFault is generated as operation.  Not sure what would be the issue:

```
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
<wsdl:operation name="ServiceException" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <soap:operation soapAction="" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
  <wsdl:fault name="ServiceExceptionFault" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <soap:fault name="ServiceExceptionFault" use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
  </wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AppPurchaseAddon" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <soap:operation soapAction="" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
  <wsdl:input name="AppPurchaseAddonRequest" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="AppPurchaseAddonResponse" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Comment: Any response would certainly help.  for now I am changing the rendering to static-wsdl where I am changing the wsdl to include service exception as fault instead of operation.